# How do I log into Ubuntu WSL Server after I've already set it up?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've setup WSL on windows 10. After the setup was complete it asked me to log into the server for the first time and set a password.

But now it's day 2, and I've rebooted my computer. How do I log into the same server I did created yesterday? Yesterday it was just automatic, but now I can't figure out how to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to open the Ubuntu Server application in the start menu or using the Cortona search bar. I prefer opening Windows Terminal and selecting the WSL distribution that I want to use from the drop-down menu.

I hope this answers your question, if it doesn't please respond.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That works!

Comment: @TimDunphy Glad it helped!

Comment: Cool! Have a nice day. :)